# SSIS Precedence Constraint not working

Tags: ssis, constraints

I have a SSIS package that has been working fine, but every once in a while, the package takes several hours to run (when it usually take no more than two minutes).

I'm trying to add a task to the package that will send me an email when the package takes longer than an hour to run.  I set up a variable that is going to calculate how long the package has been running using a variable defined as:

```
datediff("n", @StartTime, getdate())
```

I set up a precedence constraint that says if the datediff is greater than 60, then send the email.  No matter what the value of the datediff variable is, the step that will send the email will not run - the package always sees the constraint as false.

Looking at the properties of the constraint, the property window will show EvaluatesTrue as True, but the next step still won't run.

Has anyone else seen this happen?  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What happens when you hardcode the time values?

Comment: could you show your expression that you are using for the conditional split?

Answer (score 0):

I tried workflow expression evaluation.it works fine for me[image]